# Kafka and clojure no subscribe method for KafkaConsumer object

Tags: java, clojure, apache-kafka

Hi i have a very odd issue,

I am unable to call the methon subscribe on a kafkaconsumber object from clojure. Below is my code.

```
(.subscribe (KafkaConsumer. {"bootstrap.servers" "127.0.0.1:9092"
                           "key.deserializer" "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
                           "value.deserializer" "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
                           "partition.assignment.strategy" "roundrobin"
                           "group.id" "clj-kafka.consumer"
                           "auto.offset.reset" "smallest"
                           "auto.commit.enable" "false"}) ["test"]))
```

The version of kafka i am using as defined in my project.clj is

```
[org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 "0.9.0.1"]
```

For safe measure I have dumped the exact methods a available for my object and subscribe is one of them meaning it can only be an argument issue ?

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html this is the documentation i am working with.

Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: What is the error you get? Btw: in 0.9.x, auto.offset.reset should be "earliest" instead of "smallest". You might also include "kafka-clients" instead of "kafka_2.10".

Comment: Thanks it worked still not entirely sure why the "kafka_2.10" didn't work. Thank you again Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kafka `0.9.x` clients are not longer included in Kafka core module but are contained in an own module `kafka-clients`.

Thus, you should include `[org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients "0.9.0.1"]` instead of `kafka_2.10`.

Btw: In `0.9.x` the values for parameter `auto.offset.reset` should be `earliest`, `latest`, or `none` (instead of `0.8.x` values `smallest` and `largest`) (see https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs)